# Diff two containers with JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, diff, innerhtml

I want to update a container with a new version without replacing it. For example:

Container1:

```
<div id="container-one">
    <p>
        <webview src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed1aw.jpg"></webview>
    </p>
    <p>
       Text
    </p>
</div>
```

Container2:

```
<div id="container-two">
    <p>
        Cool intro
        <webview src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed1aw.jpg"></webview>
    </p>
    <p>
       Long text
    </p>
    <p>
       New Paragraph with text in it.
    </p>
</div>
```

Container1 updated:

```
<div id="container-one">
    <p>
        Cool intro
        <webview src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed1aw.jpg"></webview>
    </p>
    <p>
       Long text
    </p>
    <p>
       New Paragraph with text in it.
    </p>
</div>
```

A `Container1.innerHTML = Container2.innerHTML`would be simple but I don't want to reload my webview so the code should detect new divs or updated content in existing divs and apply the modifications in Container1.

UPDATE :

Container2 is a new version of container1 edited by a user, so Container2 can have anything in it: images, links, new paragraphs.

How can I do this?

Comment: why don't you just wrap the texts into id'd containers (div, span, whatever) and do it that way?

Comment: but you said in your question that the paragraphs are text... have I misunderstood something...? Have a look at my answer...

Answer (score 2):

I might have not understood your question correctly, but by adding an id to the text that you want to replace, and using simple javascript, you can achieve this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container-one">
    <p>
        <span id="inner-one-1"></span>
        <webview src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed1aw.jpg"></webview>
    </p>
    <p>
       <span id="inner-one-2">Text</span>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="container-two">
    <p>
        <span id="inner-two-1">Cool intro</span>
        <webview src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed1aw.jpg"></webview>
    </p>
    <p>
       <span id="inner-two-2">Long text</span>
    </p>
</div>

<button id="click">Click Me!</button>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("click").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("inner-one-2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("inner-two-2").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("inner-one-1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("inner-two-1").innerHTML;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qN9d5/)**

Comment: I update my question with more details, this is not the answer I wanted but thanks for your help.

Comment: So all you want is to add the text in the first paragraph but replace the second?

Comment: Container2 is a new version of container1 edited by a user, so Container2 can have anything in it: images, links, new paragraphs.

Comment: and...? what's wrong with my code, what is it **not** doing that you want to do?

Comment: Working with id seems a really dirty way to do this, it works but a solution working with childrens of the container would be really better.

Comment: Your idea is great, but it's still static. Container2 can have anything in it!

Answer (score 2):

you need to get the text node and replace the content, like

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    // this block is for not to update the webview
    // get the first text node
    var txt = $('#container-one > p:first').contents().first().get(0);

    if (txt.nodeType === 3) { // Node.TEXT_NODE
        txt.nodeValue = $('#container-two > p:first').text();
    }

    // update rest of the elements
    $('#container-two').children().each(function (i) {
        if (i !== 0 && $('#container-one').children()[i]) {
            $($('#container-one').children()[i]).html($(this).html());
        }
        if (!$('#container-one').children()[i]) {
            $('#container-one').append($(this).clone());
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wJ8BR/4/)

Comment: This answer is also static, what if Container2 has four paragraphs?

Comment: @armandG. see my updated code, hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

please try it.

```
var container_one = $("#container-one").children();
var container_two = $("#container-two").children();


$.each(container_one, function(index, element){
  var cont_one_html = $(this).html();
  var cont_two_html = $(container_two[index]).html();
  if(cont_one_html != cont_two_html){
    $(this).html(cont_two_html);
  }
});
```

please have a look on image [image]for more understanding.

Comment: This is great! The only thing is that if a user changes something in the paragraph it will be updated, even if the webview in the paragraph has not been changed. Could it works with children().children() to be smarter?

Comment: exactly, this code will not work, you have to update some part of this code. I can not get what is in your mind. if you will provide your code only then i can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try and see if this works for you.

```
var first = $('container-one p:first');
first.html($('container-two p:first').html() + first.html());

$('container-one p:last').html($('container-two p:last').html());
```

Comment: Container2 is a new version of container1 edited by a user, so Container2 can have anything in it: images, links, new paragraphs. It's not static at all.

Comment: `html()` will take any content as long as it recides inside the p element.

Comment: An example: If a user adds a new paragraph your code doesn't modify the second paragraph, even if it has new content. Your code work with a specific disposition of new content, this is the problem (I'm sorry my question wasn't clear at the beginning).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
function update(s){
   document.getElementById("container-one").innerHTML=s.innerHTML;
}

setInterval(function(){
   update(document.getElementById("container-two"));
},1000);
```

What this does is it updates the content once every second.

To show that it can handle dynamic content, I have made the second div editable.

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/5RLV2/2